# Geometric Series - absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

How would I determine if the following series is absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent?

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n$$\sqrt[n]{2}+1$

Comment: Firstly, this series is not geometric. Secondly, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to begin with the root test but got confused pretty quick

Comment: Well the root test is just going to introduce another root, so, you will have a root of a root, which isn't really any simpler. The root test is good when you have $n$th powers, not $n$th roots.

For a rough heuristic as to orders to test series convergence, I suggest doing the divergence test first i.e. does the *sequence* $(\sqrt[n]{2} + 1)$ tend to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\sqrt[n]2+1)$?

Comment: yes thats what i meant

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]2+1=1+1=2\neq0$. Hence the series diverges.